# class initialization list

Tags: c++, initialization

Just a simple question about c++ coding style,

for example, all member variables of a class will be called with the default constructor in the initialization list if we don't do anything else. B default constructor will be called and value will be set to 0, int();

```
class A
{
   A();
private:
   B b;
   int value;
}
```

However my question is, even do the default constructor will be called is it a good habit to always do it yourself or does it only add extra lines to the code

> A::A() : b(), value() {}

Comment: Is it always a good idea to type out A::A() { } even if it's empty?

Comment: well if you dont write : b(), value(), the compile will do it for you so is it unnecessary and only use the initialization list when you have an argument to give the constructor or when you want to set for example an int to value that is not zero

Comment: no, POD types (such as `value`) won't be intialized without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to leave the default constructor out. The compiler-generated constructors are much more reliable and maintainable than writing your own versions, and apart from anything else, it's a flat out waste of time to write code the compiler could write for you. If you don't need any construction logic, then don't write a constructor.

However, the `int` will not be initialized unless you do it, which is a sucky reason to have to write a constructor.

Comment: (+1) Confirm. Changing the order of attribues within the class result also in refactoring the list -- representing the initialisation order.

Comment: In most cases I agree. But if the class contains POD members then I would add an explicit constructor to make sure the object is in a defined state after construction. Unless the class is really just an object bag (like above) in which case I would make it a struct to reflect that fact.

Comment: @Raphael B.: Most compilers will warn you about this (and since I always compile with warnings treated as errors) thus prevent you missing the change.

Answer (score 4):

You are touching on one of the sticky corners of C++.

The initialization of POD values in objects is sticky and depends on a few things.
Even I am not sure I can get all the rules correct but I believe @Steve Jessop once wrote an article about here on SO (though I can currently find it).

But some examples:

> This class will always be initialized b == false and value = 0.

```
class A
{
   A() : b(), value() {}
   B b;
   int value;
};
```

Without an **explicit** default constructor it is more complex:
Here the compiler will generate a default constructor for you. But how the *compiler generated default constructor* works depends on the situation. The *compiler generated default constructor* can do two different forms of initialization and which is used depends on context:

1. Zero Initialization (All POD members are zero'ed out)
2. Value Initialization (All POD members are left undefined)

Example:

```
class B
{
   B b;
   int value;
};

// Variables of static storage duration (notably globals)
// Will be zero initialized and thus b == false and value = 0

B   global; // Initialized

int main()
{
    // Object of automatic storage duration or dynamic storage duration
    // These will depend on how they are declared.

    // Value Initialization (POD re-mains undefined)
    B    bo1;           // b/value undefined
    B*   bp1 = new B;   // b.balue undefined

    // Zero Initialization
    B    bo2 = B();     // b = false, value = 0
    B*   bp2 = new B(); // b = false, value = 0

    // Note: The most obvious syntax for zero initializing a local object
    //        does not work as it is actually interpreted as a forward
    //        declaration of a function;
    B   bo3(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default int variables are not initialized with a value - you have to do it yourself.

So when you don't set the member variable "value" to some value in the constructor it is left uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor will only be called for class types with default constructors, not for primitives.