# Optimal Code for initialization

Tags: c++

Which of the following code would be optimal for initializing array?

```
char szCommand[2048] ={0}
```

---

```
char szCommand[2048];
memset(szCommand,0,2048);
```

Comment: just add `'\0'` at the end of the string

Comment: See this almost identical question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1998752/57428

Comment: @maanu, how much performance benefit do you require?

Comment: Do you need it to be zero? Can you assign it the **real** value immediately instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For null terminated strings, in my opinion, the optimal initialization is this

```
szCommand[0] = 0;
```

Comment: @ybungalobill, yes. I posted an alternative way which the OP might find it ok.

Comment: There's nothing 'objective' about the difference between setting one byte vs 2048 bytes to zero.  One byte is enough if this is really a string.

Answer (score 5):

The second is not initializing the array, it's more like assigning to it. I think if ever there would be any noticeable difference (there won't be) you'd have to profile it yourself and see that the first version might be a tiiiiiny bit faster - but that's only when the optimizations are off. ***Premature optimization is the root of all evil - just DON"T think about it***

Answer (score 3):

The performance difference between the two versions would be so insignificant (if the compiler doesn't optimize away the difference) that I'd be inclined to **go with the most readable one**.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent compiler should emit the same code for both cases. In the case of `memset`, the compiler can eliminate the function call by understanding the semantics of the functions from the standard library.

Comment: However, some compilers implement memset as an intrinsic, and it is also possible that the opposite is the case and the compiler will replace the first code sample with the second one. The memory must be cleared in both cases, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Both are same, first version is compact - that's it.