# Null vs ZeroMemory

Tags: c++, c, winapi, null, directx

What exactly is the difference between setting an object to NULL and using ZeroMemory?

I hear that it is good practice in the WinAPI (which is mostly C) that a person should use ZeroMemory on C objects. I come from a background of C# and this seems like something a C++ guy should really know.

I found that with the DirectX API, whether you ZeroMemory the objects or not, the application still works, but some samples use ZeroMemory and some don't.

Can anyone clarify these things?

Comment: This article is helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/28/433341.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which one to use - memset() or value initialization to zero out a struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998752/which-one-to-use-memset-or-value-initialization-to-zero-out-a-struct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ZeroMemory` fills a block of memory with zeros.

Setting pointer to NULL will just make the pointer to points to nothing, and it is is different than filling memory which pointer is pointing to with zeros (you will still be able to access that memory via that pointer, for example).

Before you can do anything useful with that object, it is likely that you will need to replace these zeros with something more meaningful - so that is why both programs that use `ZeroMemory` or not works.

Reason for `ZeroMemory` in this context is that you could easily find operations on objects which are not initialized at the point of access (for example, Visual Studio is filling uninitialized memory with `0x0c0c0c0c` /* or similar */, so when you encounter this pattern during debugging, you know that object has not been initialized yet).

Comment: Ahh! That makes A LOT of sense! Now I know a good reason for why a person should `ZeroMemory`.

Comment: exactly confirms my idea perfect description

Comment: Note that if you're zeroing for security reasons, like password/keys, you want to use SecureZeroMemory() as a regular ZeroMemory can be optimized away in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

It's completely different things. [ZeroMemory macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fills a block of memory with zeros. Setting pointer to NULL... well it makes it pointing to nowhere.

Examples. Assume you have pointer `p` to object `o` of type "Type":

```
struct Type
{
    int i;
    float f;
    bool b;
};
Type o;
Type* p = &o;

// In memory that will be something like this:
// "o" internals = [010101010001010010110010010010100011001001010000011...]
// "p" address = 0x00830748
//(number of bits and hex adress is just example)
```

**If you `ZeroMemory` it:**

```
ZeroMemory(&o, sizeof(o));
// ---- or -----
ZeroMemory(p, sizeof(o));

// In memory we will have:
// "o" internals = [000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...]
// "p" address = 0x00830748
```

All variables inside `o` is now has value of zero:

```
cout << o.i; // 0
cout << o.f; // 0.0f
cout << o.b; // false

cout << p->i; // 0
cout << p->f; // 0.0f
cout << p->b; // false
```

**If you `NUll`-ify pointer:**

```
p = NULL;
// In memory we now have:
// "o" internals = [010101010001010010110010010010100011001001010000011...]
// "p" address = 0x00000000
```

If now you dereference `p` you will get undefined behavior:

```
int a = p->i; // Access voilation reading location 0x00000000
```

**If you `NUll`-ify object:**
It will not compile, if `Type` don't have overloaded operator=()

```
o = NULL; // error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found 
          // which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' 
          // (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

**Applying it to DirectX**

When you using DirectX, you must fill-in some structs to pass them to API functions. Here is where the magic. You can `ZeroMemory`it to values of 0, which is mostly default ones, and then just fill-in needed values, simplifying your code and keeping you from mistakes with strange values (if you create object and will not set some member variable, it will contain garbage value).

Comment: Wow! Great detailed answer! Should a person always `ZeroMemory` before setting to `NULL` when the object is POD?

Comment: @Mark Why are you obsessed with zeroing things? Call `ZeroMemory` (or `memset(..., 0, ...)` if you want to zero memory. Don't if you don't.

Comment: @Mark Russ No, you shouldn't do it always. But do it if you need to do it =)

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, "an object" cannot be set to `NULL`. *Pointers* to objects can be set to `NULL`, which means that the pointer itself points as nothing ("the null object").

This is distinct from setting the contents of an object to "all bits zero", which is what [`ZeroMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does. You can typically only do this for `structs`, not full-fledged C++ objects which might react very badly.

Answer (score 2):

ZeroMemory() sets the memory with the value 0. That is it will clear the memory. Also setting an object(pointer to the object) to NULL means the base address of that object is initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`ZeroMemory` is for setting larger chunks of memory to zero. It should not be used on objects that aren't "POD" (plain old data), that is if your object has a constructor or virtual methods.

`NULL` is used to indicate a pointer is pointing at "nothing".

Technically, you will get the same result from `ZeroMemory(pointer, sizeof(pointer));` as `pointer = NULL;`, but a) the second is clearer, and b) it is most likely as fast or faster to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

`Zero memory` sets part of memory to zero and it's harmful to use for objects more common for setting a large vector to zero and it works fast and about `Null` it's more common when you want a pointer points to nothing and their usage depends on your program pointers or setting a memory value

Answer (score 0):

In terms of good practice, id recommend you to use both.

```
// Consider mystuff as being a pointer to an object.
ZeroMemory(mystuff); // Makes this part of memory to be clean
mystuff = NULL; // Makes this pointer point to null so you dont access a 0-memory section.
```

You may when using DirectX API allocate memory with malloc, in that case a call to `ZeroMemory();` will not work as intended. For memory allocated by `malloc();` you should probably do a call to `free();` instead. When dealing with pointers I mostly set them to NULL right after releasing them, idk if thats a good practice or not.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` sets an arithmetic type variable or a (data or function) pointer variable equal to 0.
Since C++11, for pointers only, `nullptr` does the same thing and is recommended to be used for the same reason; it's proper and idiomatic.

However `ZeroMemory` set the contents of a `struct` or `class` equal to 0 byte-per-byte.

`ZeroMemory` (or `RtlZeroMemory`) is a preprocessor define of `memset` with the second argument set to `0`.

```
void* memset(void* dest, int ch, std::size_t count);

#define ZeroMemory(dest,count) memset((dest),0,(count))
```

You could say `ZeroMemory` is `memset`ing to `0`.

Example:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBuffDesc;
ZeroMemory(&indexBuffDesc, sizeof(indexBuffDesc));
// or:
memset(&indexBuffDesc,0,sizeof(indexBuffDesc));
```

`ZeroMemory` is like formatting a drive (not Quick Format).

Think `NULL`/`nullptr` as erasing the door of a strong vault full of treasure, as such you will never be able to gain access to it. Whereas, `ZeroMemory` is destroying the contents of the strong vault nullifying all treasure and everything else inside; you can gain access to it, but there's nothing in there. That's how I think about them.