# Speed of memset Vs direct assignment to zero

Tags: c, struct

Please consider a struct definition below.

```
struct xyz {
  char a;
  void *ptr;
  uint16_t num1;
  uint32_t num2;
  uint64_t num3;
};
```

I can initialize an instance of this structure to zero in one of 3 ways as below.

1. At time of declaration

   ```
   struct xyz instance = { 0 };
   ```
2. Sometime after declaring it using the C-99 feature.

   ```
   instance = (const struct xyz) { 0 };
   ```

3.`memset (&instance, 0, sizeof (struct xyz));`

A typical C struct could have some padding added by the compiler for alignment purpose.
So memset will initialize the padding bytes also to zero.

My question is:

In general, will initialization by method 1 or 2 above be faster than method 3?
It doesn't matter how many CPU cycles are saved, I am just curious if 1 & 2 are faster than 3 or not.

Comment: It also depends on where the variable is defined. If it's a global variable, you don't have to to any explicit initialization, as it will be "cleared" anyway. If it's a local (automatic) variable then method 1 is the natural way to initialize it, followed by method 3. Method 2 could possibly be optimized into method 3 by the compiler, but if not then involves both an initialization of a dummy temporary structure followed by a copy. I suggest you look at the generated (and optimized) assembly code for all three alternatives and compare them.

Comment: 1  and 2 are different from 3. `{0}` will always set pointers to `NULL`, where as `memset` doesn't if representation of null pointer is not all bits zero on given system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a quality of implementation issue.

<sup>(BTW, in pure theory, an implementation might have a `NULL` pointer which is not an all zero bits word; for such cases the semantics of your §3 is different than those of §1 or §2; but in practice, most common processors today have a linear virtual address space and have their `NULL` pointer be a word of all zero bits)</sup>

Recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) compilers (at least on usual x86-64 processors), with optimizations enabled (e.g. `gcc -O2`) are likely to produce the *same* (or very similar) machine code (because `memset` gets expanded as `__builtin_memset` which gets specifically compiled and often inlined), so using `memset` is *not* slower in practice (and could even become faster because of vectorization, e.g. [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) machine instructions)

You could look at the assembler code produced with e.g. `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O2 -march=native`

<sup>(in some cases, notably when `struct xyz` has hundreds of fields, the compiler would even synthesize a call to `memset` for your case 1 and 2!)</sup>

> In general, will initialization by method 1 or 2 above be faster than method 3?

In practice the answer is generally no (so prefer the most *readable* approach). If you care that much, benchmark your code.

<sup>(don't forget that development time also costs money; in many cases your human time is worth more than the few CPU nanoseconds you might win, and generally won't)</sup>

Comment: *If you care that much, benchmark your code.*  That probably belongs as a separate answer, in a giant red flashing font.  I'd vote it up... ;-)