# GCC: Zeroing a struct

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, padding, memset

Why does gcc create different assembly code for the following functions to zero out a struct?

```c
typedef struct {
    char a;
    int b;
} A;

void f(A *x) {
    memset(x, 0, sizeof(*x));
}

void g(A *x) {
    x->a = 0;
    x->b = 0;
}

void h(A *x) {
    *x = (A) {0};
}
```

Assembly (`-Ofast`):

```
f:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        ret
g:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+4], 0
        ret
h:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], 0
        ret
```

I assume it's because of padding of the data structure, but is gcc not allowed to override padding bytes, because they must not used anyway? I actually would expect that `f`, `g` and `h` produce identical code.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect it to produce the same code? You are assuming certain optimizations which are not documented or guaranteed.

Comment: I expect it, because gcc usually heavily optimizes and I wondering why it doesn't do it in this case.

Comment: I think `h` might be undefined behavior actually. `b` wasn't assigned.

Comment: @MooingDuck Nope, it's not UB

Comment: @KevinMeier  You are expecting GCC to figure out that that multiple assignments to different fields of a struct are actually constituting a full struct zeroing. It might be too much to ask. What if there are other statements between these two?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189856/speed-of-memset-vs-direct-assignment-to-zero

Comment: `clang++` makes `g` and `h` the same (as your `g`)

Comment: And indeed, if this struct is a field of a union, which has additional fields overlapping with the padding, it will make a difference in the behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I would actually consider this behavior more correct

Comment: @EugeneSh. As long as the result is the same I prefer the fastest way. Are we sure that `mov QWORD` is faster than `mov BYTE` + `mov DWORD`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Well the code is definitely shorter, which could contribute to it being faster.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't know enough about how modern assembler works but shorter doesn't always mean faster. At least it didn't back in my Z80 days :-) Perhaps the two operations can be done faster in parallell and the `memset` is actually a pessimization? Pure speculation on my behalf. I have no idea how it really works.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have modified the OPs code to have the struct contained in the union: https://godbolt.org/z/d5Yzxo1c6 and it looks like `g` and `h` are still different leading to different behaviors. So there is either UB somewhere or GCC has a bug clang doesn't. *Upd:* sorry, the optimization flag is incorrect on that link, but it does not change the behavior

Comment: @EugeneSh. Are you referring to the changed padding bytes? If so, the observable effect is still the same (since they are not supposed to carry any information). I don't think you have any guarantees what happens to the padding bytes and I think both zeroing them and leaving them untouched is conforming.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code I provided is demonstrating difference in observable behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, if you rely on something not guaranteed by the standard (as I think your code does).

Comment: @TedLyngmo So as I said, there might be a UB or implementation defined behavior somewhere here, but someone should point it out.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have never read the C standard so I'm not up to it. I _think_ what happens to the padding bytes is totally up to the implementation. Perhaps a [tag:language-lawyer] tag would get someone with better knowledge to chime in.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sure thing. I could do it if I weren't too lazy now :) But this is mainly to justify my point that I consider Clang behavior more correct - as it at least provides consistent behavior over two different methods of struct assignment. I understand that this consistency might not be guaranteed

Comment: @EugeneSh. The difference in observable behavior is due to unspecified behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. 6.2.6.1/6 for reference.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah, was just about to post this reference too :) Here the link http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p6 . p7 seem to be relevant too

Answer (score 1):

In the case of f, you are implicitly casting to `void*`, so `memset()` shouldn't make assumptions about what is pointed to by `x`.

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```