# Why does initializing a string member of a zeroed struct with "" cause a crash but not if the string has length of 1 or greater?

Tags: c++, string, struct, c++17, memset

I am using g++ with the c++ 17 standard

In the accepted answer for question [memset() or value initialization to zero out a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998752/memset-or-value-initialization-to-zero-out-a-struct) it states that

```cpp
struct TestStruct
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

TestStruct t = {};  // OK

{
    TestStruct t1;
    memset(&t1, 0, sizeof t1);  // ruins member 'b' of our struct
}  // Application crashes here
```

whereas in my own testing the program does not crash at this point.

Example A:

```cpp
struct TestStruct
{
  int a;
  std::string b;
};

TestStruct t1;
memset(&t1, 0, sizeof t1);

t1.b = "before";
std::cout << t1.b << std::endl;
std::cout << "after";
```

This prints

before

after

Example B:

```cpp
struct TestStruct
{
  int a;
  std::string b;
};

TestStruct t1;
memset(&t1, 0, sizeof t1);

t1.b = "";
std::cout << t1.b << std::endl;
std::cout << "after";
```

This prints nothing as the program crashes directly after
t1.b = "";

For the sake of thoroughness I also tested with t1 going out of scope as in the referenced question

```cpp
struct TestStruct
{
  int a;
  std::string b;
};

{
  TestStruct t1;
  memset(&t1, 0, sizeof t1);

  t1.b = "before";
  std::cout << t1.b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "eventually";
```

prints

before

after

eventually

My main question is, why does example B crash where example A does not?

Comment: You can only use `memset` on objects that are trivial.  `std::string` is not a trivial type.

Comment: You can use `std::is_trivially_copyable<TestStruct>::value` to see if `TestStruct` complies with [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) requirements.  (Spoiler: it does not.  q.v. [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable))

Comment: The program has undefined behavior meaning anything could happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output or even crashing. Don't rely(or make conclusions based on) on the output of a program that has UB.